# What plant is this? Zone 8. Looks like a yucca

Tags: identification

I am in Zone 8 and it was in my yard behind my fence. I decided to dig it up and plant it. It was in a moist shady area.https://photos.app.goo.gl/QPFyNwgdhdhYu32F6

Comment: Does the plant have a somewhat triangular stem?

Comment: No. It's a flat stem

Comment: Darn, then my possible ID fails. Thanks for checking it. What part of the world are you in?

Comment: After closer inspection. Yes it is a small traingle at the base of the stem

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/HeBTspH5NM7kZqSHA

Comment: Central Alabama